# Remove record from SQL table and all associated files from file system

Tags: php

I have following php code, I try to remove record from SQL table and all associated image files from file system.
I use glob() function with variable $list so get all image files start from $list and give output to unlink function but it doesn't work, I believe I do something wrong here:

```
<?
define('SITE',true);
include("../adm/conf.php");
$del=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM notes WHERE id = 26571"); 
$count=mysql_num_rows($del);
if(@$count){
    while($q=mysql_fetch_assoc($del)){
        $p_del=mysql_query("SELECT LEFT(logo,LOCATE('_',logo) - 1) imagefile FROM `notes` WHERE id_message = '".$q['id']."'");   
        if(@mysql_num_rows($p_del)){
            while($list=mysql_fetch_assoc($p_del)){             
                $filename=glob($list ."*");
                if(file_exists("../upload/notes/".$filename))unlink("../upload/notes/".$filename);
            }
        }
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM notes WHERE id='".$q['id']."'");       
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks,
S

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.0+.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`glob()` always returns an array, consisted results, and `$list` is also an array, so it should be

```
foreach ($list as $itemToDelete) {
    $filenames=glob($itemToDelete ."*");
    foreach($filenames as $filename) {
        if(file_exists("../upload/notes/".$filename)) {
            unlink("../upload/notes/".$filename);
        }
    }
}
```

I would recommend for more short and clear search/deleting as

```
while($list=mysql_fetch_assoc($p_del)){
    foreach ($list as $itemToDelete) {   
        array_map('unlink', glob("../upload/notes/{$itemToDelete}*"));
    }
}
```

Comment: tried with array_walk but for some reason doesn't work

Comment: maybe it doesn't like {$list}* in quote in glob?

Comment: Double quotes make available to include variable's value to a string.

Comment: Are you sure that $list has any value? I see error suppressing, it's not good practice and can lead to unknown errors.

Comment: Here how I put: while($q=mysql_fetch_assoc($del)){
  $p_del=mysql_query("SELECT LEFT(logo,LOCATE('_',logo) - 1) imagefile FROM `jb_news` WHERE id_message = '".$q['id']."'");   
  if(@mysql_num_rows($p_del)){
   while($list=mysql_fetch_assoc($p_del)){
               array_walk('unlink', glob("../upload/news/{$list}*"));
                }
              }
           }

Comment: Have you debugged that `$list` has any value by that point? For example, does `var_dump($list) ` output any value?

Comment: it gives output for $list it seems unlink or glob doesn't like it

Comment: Since `$list` is an array too, I updated my code.

Comment: With first method script run but doesn't remove files, with second method(array_walk) script doesn't run.

Comment: Fixed. I strongly recommend to enable PHP errors, as was suggested in your's post comment, so you could easily see any code mistakes and their reasons.

Comment: sorry, you said Fixed, what did you fix?

Comment: I see you changed to array_map.

Comment: now the second method runs but doesn't remove the files, trying to debug it but don't know how get the output to the browser inside while.

Comment: I've tested unlink locally, so I believe the problem is behind there's so files at all in the noted directory.
You can output result like this:
```php
while($list=mysql_fetch_assoc($p_del)){
    foreach ($list as $itemToDelete) {  
        var_dump(%info you need%); 
        array_map('unlink', glob("../upload/notes/{$itemToDelete}*"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I also suggest to google for some material about debugging a web application, it would be definitely better explained than I could do that =)

Comment: sorry, the second method works, my fault the second sql query field name in condition was wrong. Thanks a lot to Alex.Default!!

Comment: and our change "foreach ($list as $itemToDelete)" with array_map perfectly works. Thanks again!!